# Algorith for comparing two names to see if the are similar/same

Tags: algorithm, comparison, string-comparison, fuzzy-comparison

I'm currently implemetning an automated workflow which has to compare a fixed name with another name and return if the name is a match or not. It should consider spelling/typo mistakes and implement a suitable algorithm like soundex/levensthein

Example fixed Name = Christopher Joel

Matches should for example be found for:

- Christopher Doe
- Joel
- Christopher Joel
- Christopker Joel

No matches should be found for:

- Marry Doe
- Christin

Maybe someone has already a suitable example for me? I thought about splitting all name parts and compare them individually, but I'm still usure here if this is the correct way.

Many thanks

Comment: Soundex doesn't consider typos you showed, I think.

Comment: The "correct" way depends on precise definition of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using https://www.npmjs.com/package/fuzzball since this required no logic at all